# fetch user name and password from URI

Tags: java, networking

Is that possible to fetch user name and password from URI using standard Java API?

```
URI uri = new URI("http://user:pass@host/some/path");
uri.getUserPassword()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible; this is the [`.getUserInfo()` method from the `URI` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#getUserInfo--). `null` if no such data.

Comment: getUserInfo() returns me string and force me to add additional logic of parsing it which I don't want to be involved in

Comment: Too bad however, you have no choice. And anyway the parsing is simple, since RFC 3986 defines it: anything before the first colon is the user, the rest is the password. Of course, no colon means no password!

Comment: 'additional parsing logic' - all of one line! String.split